# syllables and pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, syllables

The word exercise has 3 syllables and divided as ex-er-cise.  In teaching pronunciation can I divide it as ek-ser-cise since the letter x is the sound of ks together?  It seems to make more sense.

Comment: You can, and in fact that's probably the best way to teach it. The word divisions for hyphenation only give the divisions for pronunciation some of the time.

Comment: It can't be said too often: There is no consistent reliable set of rules for pronouncing English words from their spelling. Throw the alphabet away except for recognizing words, and use phonemics for teaching pronunciation. [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse?ui=embed#page/n5/mode/2up) is free online, and here's a [chart of American phonemes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) with an example transcription.

Comment: Thank you Peter and John. You guys have been so helpful and having that link to Kenyon and Knott is a gem.

Comment: the phonetic spelling should be more like 'ek-sir-size'

Answer (score 1):

That is how the Miriam-Webster dictionary does it:

**exercise**

```
  noun ex·er·cise \ˈek-sər-ˌsīz\
```

Answer (score 0):

Different reference works have different ways of dividing words into syllables. There's >usually< no issue about how many syllables a word has, but rather concerning where the breaks fall. My own practice is to honor the etymology where this is possible, as in lob-o-to-my, not lo-bot-o-my [Merriam Webster], or psy-cho-log-ist, not psy-chol-o-gist [American Heritage], Is "bot" a proper word element? Is "chol"?

Comment: It would be great if we all said 'loeb-oe-toem-ee', but you shouldn't blindly honor the etymology if you are teaching common prounciation.